# Accordion on click issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to fix that Boostrap Accordion was not working properly initially it was showing all headings and content under that directly. After double click on any tab its working properly . But again when i am refresh the page same problem repeated i was tried a lot here is my code and image

```
 $content.='<div style="width:600px; margin:auto;">
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">';
  while ($activation_row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
                $dobarray1 = explode('-', $activation_row['date1']);
                $date = $dobarray1[2] . '/' . $dobarray1[1] . '/' . $dobarray1[0]; 
                $uid=$activation_row['id'];                 
                $content.='<div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne'.$uid.'">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne'.$uid.'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        '.$date.' '.date("h:i:s A", strtotime($activation_row['time1'])).'
                </a>
                </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne'.$uid.'" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne'.$uid.'">
                <div class="panel-body">
                                ' . stripcslashes($activation_row['workflow']) . '
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>';            
            }
$content.='</div></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey i found solution for this issue :

```
  class="panel-collapse collapse in"
```

in this class remove "in" form this class ( class="panel-collapse collapse { in }" )

if u want first tab to open you need to put a counter variable increment in while loop. When the value is " 1 " then add " in " to class otherwise don't add

```
 $content.='<div style="width:600px; margin:auto;">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">';
            $count = 1; 
            while ($activation_row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
            $final = $count++;
                $dobarray1 = explode('-', $activation_row['date1']);
                $date = $dobarray1[2] . '/' . $dobarray1[1] . '/' . $dobarray1[0]; 
                $uid=$activation_row['id'];

                $content.='<div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne'.$uid.'">
                          <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne'.$uid.'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                              '.$date.' '.date("h:i:s A", strtotime($activation_row['time1'])).'
                            </a>
                          </h4>
                        </div>';
                            if($final==1){
                             $content.='<div id="collapseOne'.$uid.'" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne'.$uid.'">';
                            }       
                            else{
                             $content.='<div id="collapseOne'.$uid.'" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne'.$uid.'">';
                            }

                             $content.='<div class="panel-body">
                                ' . stripcslashes($activation_row['workflow']) . '
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>';
```